# Unable to print Unicode string using wprintf in FASM or NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, nasm, fasm

I'm having trouble printing a Unicode string using the wprintf function in FASM (Flat Assembler).

I've tried the following code, but it produces random output (αñ╣αñ┐αñ¿αÑìαñ┐):

```
format PE64 console
entry start

include './include/win64w.inc'
include './include/macro/proc64.inc'
include './include/encoding/utf8.inc'

;======================================
section '.data' data readable writeable
;======================================
;unicode for हिन्दी
wunicode_string dw  0xe0, 0xa4, 0xb9, 0xe0, 0xa4, 0xbf, 0xe0, 0xa4, 0xa8, 0xe0, 0xa5, 0x8d, 0xe0, 0xa4, 0xbf



;=======================================
section '.code' code readable executable
;=======================================

start:
    
    mov rax, 0
    ccall [wprintf], "%ls", wunicode_string
   

    ccall   [getchar]                   ; I added this line to exit the application AFTER the user pressed any key.
    stdcall [ExitProcess],0             ; Exit the application

;====================================
section '.idata' import data readable
;====================================

library kernel,'kernel32.dll',        msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll'

import  kernel,        ExitProcess,'ExitProcess'

import  msvcrt,        printf,'printf', wprintf, 'wprintf',       getchar,'_fgetchar'
```

Comment: What if you change the string to `wunicode_string dw  0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44` (aka ABCD)?

Comment: So it's probably printing exactly the characters you are telling it to print.  What do you expect to see?

Comment: I want to see हिन्दी whose unicode I got from [this](https://www.coderstool.com/unicode-text-converter) website

Comment: Ahh.  Sorry, it's right there in your post.  Unicode characters are 16 bits long, so using `dw` is correct.  But then it looks like you are only specifying 8 bits: `0xe0`.  Should that be `0xe0a4`?  Or maybe `0xa4e0`?

Comment: I don't think I have the right code pages installed to display it here, but perhaps `wunicode_string du "हिन्दी"`?  Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388490/2189500) seems to suggest that while the Windows *console* supports everything unicode, the c *runtime* via stdout?  Not so much.

Comment: `wunicode_string du "हिन्दी"` shows blank output, interestingly all the unicode containing English characters whether UTF-8 or 16 are showed correctly. The same thing in C code works flawlessly on the same console. Should I try WinAPI?

Comment: I've tried using WriteConsoleW, but it didn't help.  But my C code doesn't show the string in a console window either so maybe it will work for you?

Comment: in C it works by default with printf using below code 
`#include <Windows.h>`
`#include <stdio.h>`

`char *s = "the हिन्दी string";`

`int main(){`
    `// set console code page to utf-8`
    `SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);`
    `printf("%s\n",s);`
    `return 0;`
}`
In FASM I got it to work using MessageBoxW but still no luck with WriteConsoleW. Is there any way to `SetConsoleOutputCP(65001);`using FASM

Comment: I got the answer (I don't have enough reputation to answer my own question, somebody answer it I will mark it as answer) So you have to import SetConsoleOutputCP from kernel32 lib and then `ccall  [SetConsoleOutputCP], 65001` and it will work

Comment: I think you have enough reputation to self answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows correct output if we set correct [code page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-code-pages) for the console which we can do in FASM (will work in NASM too) like below:

```
format PE64 console
entry start

include './include/win64a.inc'
include './include/macro/proc64.inc'


;=======================================
section '.code' code readable executable
;=======================================

start:

    ccall   [SetConsoleOutputCP], 65001
    ccall   [printf], "%s", "हिन्दी"


    ccall   [getchar]                   ; I added this line to exit the application AFTER the user pressed any key.
    stdcall [ExitProcess], 0            ; Exit the application

;====================================
section '.idata' import data readable
;====================================

library kernel,'kernel32.dll',\  
        msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll'

import  kernel,\  
        ExitProcess,'ExitProcess',\  
        SetConsoleOutputCP, 'SetConsoleOutputCP'

import  msvcrt,\  
        printf,'printf',\  
        getchar,'_fgetchar'
```

I've used `printf` but it will work for `wprintf` too.